# Shortening str.replace()

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

In Python it is often necessary to use `str.replace(a,b)`, however `.replace` is rather long and feels unnecessary. So is there a shorter alternative to `str.replace`.

Alternatively is there a similar trick to how you can use `r=range` for golfing for `str.replace`?

### Example code for golfing

```
m=input()
f="hello"
print m.replace('t','Ushd')
print m.replace('h','gyhj')
print f.replace('o','%£&')
```

Comment: `r=str.replace; print r('abc', 'b', 'c')`?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Nope, Python doesn't work like that unfortunately :(

Comment: Uh, yes it does. I just tried it now in Python 2, Python 3, Skulpt, and PyPy.js.

Comment: @BetaDecay How many downvotes do you need until you believe it?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Well whaddaya know, that's brilliant, thanks

Comment: @flawr -15 once again! ;P

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate. Aliasing the function is a possible solution, but there might be others using different functions or methods.

Comment: @xnor True, but the second half of the question is just asking for a dupe of the question I linked. If it is removed, I will retract my vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r=str.replace;print r('abc','b','c')
```

The magic is real.

[Shortening str.replace()](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60238/shortening-str-replace?noredirect=1#comment144890_60238)

Answer (score 3):

#### Regex Replace

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), but it will take several uses to pay off if you're only doing it one character at a time.

```python
import re
s="hello"
r=s.replace('h','m')
r=re.sub('h','m',s)
```

#### Translate

You may also wish to look at [`string.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate), which can be used for large numbers of single-character replacements. **Requires Python 3.** If using Python 2, `maketrans` is required first. For an example, [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21038977/2415524) In Python 3, it's used like this (taking a literal dictionary of ASCII values):

```python
print("hello".translate({104:109}))
```

Output:

```
mello
```

Comment: You don't need to use `maketrans`, try `"hello".translate({104:105})`. This is a trick some python golfers have used in the past

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah right. I always forget you can do that, since the documentation doesn't show that anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Just realized that requires Python 3. Edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: Also `re.sub` fails if you use regex metachars.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy No it doesn't, you just have to escape them as a regex string like `r'\'` or with a backslash like `'\\'`.

Comment: Though it becomes pointless if your search is `r"\.\.\.\.\.\.\.\."` Too many backslashes. (Also `r"something"` is called a raw string.)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy The entire premise of the question was to replace a single character at a time. And if that's your search, you'd do string multiplication.